# c# lambda dictionary, char[] selecting items

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, dictionary

I'm not the best with lambda can anyone teach me how to select items from a dictionary using a character array.

say I have a dictionary;

```
Dictionary<char, int> someDictionary:
```

and i have a character array;

```
char[] someCharacterArray;
```

how do I select items from the dictionary using a collection of keys stored in a char array;

```
someOtherDictionary = someDictionary.select( d =>
    someCharacterArray.contains(d.key)).toDictionary();
```

I know that doesn't work of course but it demonstrates what i want.

hope my question is clear but I've been awake all night so be gentle with me :)

thanks in advance,
Darren.

Comment: This really isn't lambda, it is Linq.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check if the char Contain in Dictionary.

use `where` method

`ToDictionary` should set `key` and `value` `Func` delegate

From your question you might want to be like this.

```
Dictionary<char, int> someOtherDictionary = someDictionary
            .Where(d => someCharacterArray.Contains(d.Key))
            .ToDictionary(o=> o.Key, o=>o.Value);
```

**Edit**

This will be faster in the data structures. (thank for @TypeIA)

```
Dictionary<char, int> someOtherDictionary = someCharacterArray
                .Where(ch => someDictionary.ContainsKey(ch))
                .Select(ch => new { key = ch, value = someDictionary[ch] })
                .ToDictionary(o => o.key, o => o.value);
```

Comment: Depending on what's in the data structures, it might be better to do it the other way around (`someCharacterArray.Where(ch => someDictionary.ContainsKey(ch)).Select(ch => someDictionary[ch])`).

Answer (score 0):

This sort of problem calls for a [Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534675(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
    Dictionary<char, int> someDictionary = new Dictionary<char,int>
    {
        {'A',1},
        {'B',2},
        {'C',3},
        {'D',4}
    };


    char[] someCharacterArray = new [] {'A','B','C','E'};


    var filteredDictionary = someDictionary
        .Join
        (
            someCharacterArray, 
            d => d.Key, 
            c => c, 
            (d,c) => new { Key = d.Key, Value = d.Value}
        )
        .ToDictionary
        (
            k => k.Key, 
            v => v.Value
        );

    Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\r\n", filteredDictionary.Select(d => string.Format("{0}={1}", d.Key, d.Value))));
```

Output:

```
A=1
B=2
```

[Code on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZopK29)